# When using parenthesis in registry name in Get-ACL command used in subprocess in python gives error

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, parentheses

```
ps_cmdlet = r'Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\{ab}" | Format-List'

p = subprocess.call(['powershell', '-Command', '& {'+ps_cmdlet+'}'],shell=True)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\{ab}' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:4
+ & {Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\{ab}" | Format-List}
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

Comment: So what's the expected behaviour?! What is `{ab}` supposed to do?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `{ab}` is a perfectly valid registry key name

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen good to know that this might be a reason - so in the end this had absolutely nothing to do with Python - I suspected that OP was attempting to do some in-place interpolation with a variable named `ab`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That may be the case as well, not sure

Comment: @AnttiHaapala When i run the same command directly on powershell, it gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets with backticks:

```
ps_cmdlet = r'Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\`{ab`}" | Format-List'
```